# How to get auto width for SVG icon inside a sprite?

Tags: css, svg, sprite, aspect-ratio

I've a problem in setting automatic width for SVG icons, preserving aspect ratio, having a fixed height for Firefox, Chrome and IE11.
I know this is a common problem and I've read examples reported in this [very good article](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/), but I cannot find a working snippet of code to make it work.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="icon-container">
  <svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="mySvgSpritePath/icons.svg#myIcon"></use>
  </svg>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .icon-container {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 230px;
    height: 75px;
  }
  .icon {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }        
</style>
```

As expected, I get the following, the icon takes the 100% width of its container:

[image]

The viewBox of my icon (`viewBox="0 0 26.81 45"`) is not visible in my markup because it's defined inside my SVG sprite, inside a `<symbol>` element.
This way I cannot use the padding hack described in the article, because I do not have access to viewBox values in my template producing the final html: if I could, I would set a dynamic padding for every different icon I can get from my sprite.

Of course, my desired output would be the following:

[image]

Have you got any suggestions, advices or even better snippets to reach this goal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In  add attribute `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"`

Use `em`

scss template:

```
.icon-{{base}} {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: ({{width.inner}} / {{height.inner}})*1em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Output:

```
.icon-medal {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 1.32em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Usage:

```
.icon-medal {
    font-size: 75px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this works: width: ({{width.inner}} / {{height.inner}})*1em;